# Is it possible to make Visual Studio call npm install when an updated package.json is downloaded from source control?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2015

I know that when I manually update the package.json file, VS will run an `npm install`. However, if someone else updates it and checks it into source control, when I download it, `npm install` doesn't get called. I have to either save package.json (even if I don't make any changes), or call it myself from a command prompt. It will be really frustrating if we have to communicate to the entire team that they each need to perform some action after getting package.json, any time a change is made.

Is this just a missing feature in Visual Studio, or am I missing something that would allow it work as expected?

Our project is still an old Webforms project (Yeah I know. It's not by the dev team's choice.), so it doesn't have the `Dependencies` node in Solution Explorer. I realize this might be the problem, and it would possibly all work correctly if we were using an ASP.NET 5 MVC project. However, saving package.json does launch `npm install`, so the basic support still works. So, if that is the problem, I'd like confirmation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried asking this on the [VS forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/74f2c9cf-b9ea-4b15-9c3f-8060cfa16bcc/is-it-possible-to-make-visual-studio-call-npm-install-when-an-updated-packagejson-is-downloaded?forum=visualstudiogeneral#74f2c9cf-b9ea-4b15-9c3f-8060cfa16bcc) also, and only got a response from a single MS CSG who obviously didn't understand what I was asking. I got tired of the frustration of trying to explain it to him, and dropped it. Since no one else responded, I'm assuming the answer is that it's not possible.

I've created a [UserVoice suggestion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/10519194-automatically-call-npm-install-when-an-updated-c) for it, and suggest everyone that has votes avilable to upvote it.

I have noticed that it does call `npm install` when you open the solution file (and probably when opening just the project file, although I haven't tried that). That's a little better, but since I usually leave VS open and just hibernate my computer at the end of the day, I don't actually open the solution/project file that often.